# What permissions on Documents library? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, file-permissions

My Windows 10 machine is not connected to a domain. I have several local users. To make space for their files, I moved their Documents libraries to a second drive, by creating a directory (`I:\users\UserA`, etc.) and setting the Documents location.

Questions:

1. Who should be the owner of `I:\users`?
2. Who should be the owner of `I:\user\UserA`?
3. What should the permissions of the files in `I:\user\UserA` be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Users` folder should be owned by `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

The individual user folder should be owned by the `SYSTEM` as well, but the individual user the folder is for should have a "full access" permission. This should be set to inherit, so the files under `I:\users\UserA` would have this at a minimum.

Comment: My Win 10 Home machine doesn´t have NT AUTHORITY, but I found a SYSTEM user

Comment: `NT AUTHORITY` is the "domain" - every user has one, even if it's hidden by default. If you don't qualify the `SYSTEM` name by including it, it will default to the correct one, so you're fine.